# How to make mathematical calculations in arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist

I'm a beginner in JavaScript.

i have two arrays which coordinates I want found maximum distance, minimum distance and total distance for all objects arr2

```
example array
var arr1 = [{"m1":{"lat":78,"lang":87}}] <- my coordinats
var arr2 = [{"m1":{"lat":47,"lang":55}},{"m2":{"lat":87,"lang":55}},{"m3":{"lat":98,"lang":22}}] <- object coordinats
```

I don't understand how to using cycle get around arr2 and put values into formula distance calculation.

### Update

I found a solution but it contains 800 lines. Any ideas how to optimize this?

```
example 
if ("geolocation" in navigator){ 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
var Mylat2 = position.coords.latitude
var Mylon2 = position.coords.longitude
//coordinats const
var i0lat1=55.111111
var i1lat1=55.222222
var i2lat1=55.333333
var i3lat1=55.444444
var i4lat1=55.555555
var i5lat1=55.666666
///much more....
var i0lon1=37.777777
var i1lon1=37.888888
var i2lon1=37.999999
var i3lon1=37.111111
var i4lon1=37.222222
var i5lon1=37.333333
///much more....

//calculation distance for each combination lon and lat from current coordinates
var p = 0.017453292519943295;    // Math.PI / 180
var c = Math.cos;
var a0 = 0.5 - c((Mylat2 - i0lat1) * p)/2 + c(i0lat1 * p) * c(Mylat2 * p) * (1 - c((Mylon2 - i0lon1) * p))/2; var i0distance = 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a0)); // 2 * R; R = 6371 km
var a1 = 0.5 - c((Mylat2 - i1lat1) * p)/2 + c(i1lat1 * p) * c(Mylat2 * p) * (1 - c((Mylon2 - i1lon1) * p))/2; var i1distance = 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a1)); 
var a2 = 0.5 - c((Mylat2 - i2lat1) * p)/2 + c(i2lat1 * p) * c(Mylat2 * p) * (1 - c((Mylon2 - i2lon1) * p))/2; var i2distance = 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a2)); 
var a3 = 0.5 - c((Mylat2 - i3lat1) * p)/2 + c(i3lat1 * p) * c(Mylat2 * p) * (1 - c((Mylon2 - i3lon1) * p))/2; var i3distance = 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a3)); 
var a4 = 0.5 - c((Mylat2 - i4lat1) * p)/2 + c(i4lat1 * p) * c(Mylat2 * p) * (1 - c((Mylon2 - i4lon1) * p))/2; var i4distance = 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a4)); 
var a5 = 0.5 - c((Mylat2 - i5lat1) * p)/2 + c(i5lat1 * p) * c(Mylat2 * p) * (1 - c((Mylon2 - i5lon1) * p))/2; var i5distance = 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a5));

//store values in array
var Distanse = [i0distance, i1distance, i2distance, i3distance, i4distance, i5distance]

// calculation max/min distance/index
var indexMax = Distanse.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, Distanse)); // max distance index
var indexMin = Distanse.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math, Distanse)); //  min index distance 
var valueMax = Math.max.apply (Math, Distanse); // max distance
var valueMin = Math.min.apply (Math, Distanse); // min distance
```

Comment: If they are supposed to be lat/lng surface points on a sphere, look up the inverse haversine formula. If it's just a 2d plane, then it's basic trigonometry. In either case if you're struggling please show what you've tried so we can help you debug it. SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: im asking for any help. i do not ask WRITE CODE FOR ME GUYS. And yes i have found function for calculation distance i just don't know how to put values from arr2

Comment: Then show that code in the question so we can help you debug it

Comment: added the code abow